# Adding multiple records to a table using radio buttons and check boxes, Access 2003

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am building a database to track field personnel's on call schedule. Typically, the employee is on call for a full week, however, they do occasionally take specific days only. I have a form in Access 2003 that has an Option Group to indicate Full Week vs. Partial Week. If the form user selects "Partial Week" it enables a set of check boxes that let's the user specify specific days (Mon, Tue, Wed, etc). What I would like to be able to do is:

If the user chooses "Full Week", the form will create 7 records, one for each day (Monday - Sunday) where all fields are the same, save for the "Day of the Week" field. However, if they choose "Partial Week", it should only create as many records as the user has chosen check boxes (so if they choose Monday and Tuesday, the form creates two records: one with "Day of the Week" equaling Monday and one with "Day of the Week" equaling Tuesday).

Is this possible in any way/shape/form?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into ..."` as many times you need as given by the radio buttons and the selected check boxes.

Comment: `db.Execute` is usually preferable to `DoCmd.RunSQL`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb()

If FullWeek Or Monday Then
    db.Execute "insert into ... " // record for Monday
End If

If FullWeek Or Tuesday Then
    db.Execute "insert into ... " // record for Tuesday
End If

// etc...

db.Close
```

Don't use `DoCmd.RunSQL`.  It is generally a bad idea because its behavior depends on user settings.  If you use the Database `Execute` method, you won't run into that problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways to accomplish what you are trying to do by defining your weekdays as a table in your database, and using a Listview with checkboxes or something. However, THIS will accomplish what you are looking for, given your current model:

EDITED CODE:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'Declare a Collection to hold references
'to your checkboxes at the form level:
Private DayCheckBoxes As Collection

'Use the Form_Load Event to set up:
Private Sub Form_Load()

    'Initialize the Form Variable:
    Set DayCheckBoxes = New Collection

    'Add each checkbox to the collection:
    With DayCheckBoxes
        .Add Me.chkSun
        .Add Me.chkMon
        .Add Me.chkTue
        .Add Me.chkWed
        .Add Me.chkThu
        .Add Me.chkFri
        .Add Me.chkSat
    End With

    'A local variable to walk the collection:
    Dim CurrentCheckBox As CheckBox

    'Walk through the controls, and set the .Tag property to
    'hold the name for each weekday. Note that in this case,
    'the weekday name is extracted from each control name:
    For Each CurrentCheckBox In DayCheckBoxes
        CurrentCheckBox.Tag = Replace(CurrentCheckBox.Name, "chk", "")
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
        Call UpdateSchedule
End Sub


Private Sub UpdateSchedule()
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()

    'Local variable used to walk the collection:
    Dim CurrentCheckBox As CheckBox

    'Walk through the collection:
    For Each CurrentCheckBox In DayCheckBoxes

        'If the checkbox is checked, execute your INSERT
        '(Assumes your optionGroup values are 1 and 2 for full and partial, respectively):
        If Me.frmFullOrPartial = 1 Or (Me.frmFullOrPartial = 2 And CurrentCheckBox) Then

            'I used a really simple INSERT to test everythiing. Put your own SQL in here:
            db.Execute "INSERT INTO ScheduledDays (DayOfWeek) VALUES ( '" & CurrentCheckBox.Tag & "' )"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, forgot the part about full week. If fullWeek is selected, walk the collection and set all the checkboxes to True. Then call UpdateSchedule.

Comment: OK. I did a quick edit to take your basic requirements into account. While this looks like more code than some of the other postings here, you will find that creating the collection of checkboxes in the Load Even and using that throughout will make maintenence easier. You will probably have to tweak the code a little to fit your design. I wasn;t sure how you are managing your option group, so I "winged" it.